# Pseudo-Apriori Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, apriori

I have an **array of objects with an ID attribute**, and I need to link them together in a table.

I would like to insert the object IDs linked together into a 2-column MySQL table.

The table in question has 2 columns: **A**, and **B**. I want to link together the collection of objects without any overlap.

I am referring to it as pseudo-apriori because it resembles the candidate-generation process of the apriori algorithm.

For the example below, I have a five objects with an ID value of 1-5. So for example: `$obj1->id == 1`, and so on.

Example table:

```
Input IDs:
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Output DB Table:
-----------
| A  |  B |
-----------
| 1  |  2 |
| 1  |  3 |
| 1  |  4 |
| 1  |  5 |
| 2  |  3 |
| 2  |  4 |
| 2  |  5 |
| 3  |  4 |
| 3  |  5 |
| 4  |  5 |
-----------
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want to compute, or how it relates to the apriori algorithm

Comment: Could you put an example of the expected outuput?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have hopefully clarified the question…

Comment: @m4t1t0 The expected output will be in a MySQL table, with the output as above

Comment: I still do not understand your question. What do you expect the output to be? **What have you tried**? If you refer to Apriori, what is an transaction here? Note that Apriori does not make sense when all your transactions have size 2.

Comment: There is no question here. It appears you want us to write code for you from start to finish?

Comment: You want all 2-combinations of a given set (with 5 elements in this example)?

Comment: @VolkerK absolutely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really don't know what you're trying to do. But if the result must be as the table example, then you can do it with the following loop:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        // add db logic here
        $q = 'insert into table (' . $arr[$i] . ', ' . $arr[$j] . ')';
    }
}
```

Here is an jsFiddle example for the output: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGpt6/)

Comment: Exactly what I somehow couldn't solve, even though I've done this a lot of times in the past. Many thanks!

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure you need the `var` word in the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

E.g. the pear package [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics/docs) can do this.

```
<?php
require 'Math/Combinatorics.php';
$c = new Math_Combinatorics;
foreach( $c->combinations(array(1,2,3,4,5), 2) as $k ) {
    echo join(', ', $k), "\n";  
}
```

prints

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
1, 5
2, 3
2, 4
2, 5
3, 4
3, 5
4, 5
```

Answer (score -2):

please visit this address: [Apriori Algorithm in PHP](http://vtwo.org/algorithm/apriori/)

**Methods**: setMaxScan(int), setMinSup(int), setMinConf(int), setDelimiter(string), getMinSup(void), getMinConf(void), getMaxScan(void), getDelimiter(void), process(string or array), printFreqItemsets(void), getFreqItemsets(void), printAssociationRules(void), getAssociationRules(void), saveFreqItemsets(string), saveAssociationRules(string)